# How can I check if dynamic variable exist?

Tags: twig

I'm working on a twig template that gets from back-end several avatar urls (avatar_url_1, avatar_url_2 etc). If I get none, I need to display a default avatar image.

ex. 
avatar_url_1 - I get a link,
avatar_url_2 - link,
avatar_url_3 - is null, no I should use a default url,
avatar_url_4 - link.

I tried

```
{% for i in range(1, 7) %}
{{ elements.avatar("*|avatar_url_" ~ i ~ "|*")}}
...
```

with this macro

```
{% macro avatar(url) %}
    <img src="{% if url | default(false) %}{{url}}{% else %}https://PATH_TO_DEFAULT_IMAGE{% endif %}" />
{% endmacro %}
```

but it doesn't work. When the variable doesn't exist the image path is broken, not using a default path.

How can I check that if every author_avatar_url_ exist without resigning from the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [`attribute`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function in conjucture with the special variable `_context`, which holds all know variables in the template.

```
{% for i in range(1, 7) %}
    {{ elements.avatar(attribute(_context, "*|avatar_url_" ~ i ~ "|*") | default(null))}}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/un2rjo)